# Nivo Slider flash in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have downloaded the nivo sldier for my own website. but it is keep on flashing in transition   which whenever it change to next image, it will be flashing or flickering in chrome but work fine in FF n IE. Has anyone encounter this problem ? THanks

Comment: Does it flash on their website?

Comment: Check the browser console for errors.

Comment: its only happened in chrome. Firefox and IE is working perfectly.